# how to detect str_replace() has done replacement or not? and how many?

Tags: php, str-replace, string-matching

I have two string, something like this:

```
$str1='this is the first text';
$str2='this is the second text';
```

Now I use `str_replace();` to replace the word of *'first'* in the `str1` and `str2`.

For `str1`: The subject will be found and then will be replaced

```
str_replace('first','matched',$str1);
// output: this is the matched text
```

For `str2`: The subject will not found and `str2` does not change.

```
str_replace('first','matched',$str2);
// output: this is the second text
```

Now I want to `echo`:

- *'matched has been find'* for `str1`
- *'matched has not been find'* for `str2`.

And also I want to know that is it possible to count the number of matched found? e.g. for `str1` is `1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a fourth `count` argument to [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) that counts the total number of replacements actually made to the string

What it won't do is tell you how many of each replacement if you're doing multiple replacements (using arrays), but it does give you the overall count

**EDIT**

```
$str1 = 'this is the first text';
$result1 = str_replace('first','matched',$str1, $counter);
echo $counter, ' replacements were made', PHP_EOL;

$result2 = str_replace('is','**',$str1, $counter);
echo $counter, ' replacements were made', PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is a [pre-defined constant](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) for an `end of line`, either `"\n"` or `"\r\n"` depending on whether your PHP is running on a *nix or Windows platform (not everyone runs there PHP to send through a web server, and `<br />` doesn't mean anything when you're executing code from the command line)

Comment: Could you not just assign a different variable to each of the 2 functions? $counter1 and $counter2 for example?

Comment: @Tarquin - Yes, I could, but why?

Comment: Was more enquiring as to whether its user controllable or set. Ive never known a 4th option existed in that function. Also the way you worded it was slightly unclear in how you stated inability to count each replacement. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The problem I indicated is if you do something like `$result = str_replace(['a','b'], ['c','d'], $string, $counter);` then you can't tell how many individual `a` were replaced with `c` and how many individual `b` were replaced with `d`, just how many total replacements there were